# Height of floral sets

Tags: sets, size

I'm planning my decor. To that end, I need to the approximate height of a few sets:

- [10311 Orchid](https://www.lego.com/en-ca/product/orchid-10311)
- [10289 Bird of Paradise](https://www.lego.com/en-ca/product/bird-of-paradise-10289)
- [10313 Wildflower Bouquet](https://www.lego.com/en-ca/product/wildflower-bouquet-10313)
- [10280 Flower Bouquet](https://www.lego.com/en-ca/product/flower-bouquet-10280)

Comment: It is delightful to hear folks planning their decor around excellent LEGO sets.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the pages you linked, under "specifications":

### 10311 Orchid

> Dimensions – This buildable model measures over 15 in. (39 cm) high, 11.5 in. (30 cm) wide and 9.5 in. (24 cm) deep

### 10289 Bird of Paradise

> As a guide, the tallest leaf limb measures over 18 in. (46 cm) high and the flowerpot measures over 5 in. (13 cm) in diameter.

### 10313 Wildflower Bouquet

> Dimensions – The stems come in a variety of lengths. As a guide, the ‘larkspur’, with its straight stem, measures over 18 in. (47 cm) tall

### 10280 Flower Bouquet

> The stems come in a variety of lengths. As a guide, the ‘snapdragon’, with its straight stem, measures over 14 in. (36 cm) high.

Don't forget that putting the bouquets in a vase adds a little bit of height, while at the same time lowering the height a little because the flowers spread out.

Generally it's probably easiest to assume ~50cm for each set when planning.

Comment: omg! It's so far down the page that I missed it. How embarrassing. Thanks.